# Different between RelatedToId vs ParentId In EmailMessage

Tags: apex, workbench, admin, emailmessage

I had task related to **Email Message** (email-to-case).

When an email arrives on closed case object, Then i was have to clone the old case object & create new record on that with exact data and also i have carry forward(copy) all email from old case object to new case object with open status of new case record.

When i copying all the email from Old case record to new case record i realize there are two fields in EmailMessage object named with **RelatedToId,ParentId.** 
But both fields are pointing to same case object.

Below image shows, email message object field names in workbench which has RelatedToId,ParentId

[image]

Below image shows, email i receive from in sales-force and created case record for this email[i config email-to-case for this ]

[image]

Both fields **RelatedToId & ParentId** has value of case object "5002C000005T93TQAS".

**So i am curious what is the Different between RelatedToId vs ParentId In EmailMessage?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EmailMessage** is only available for organizations that use **Email-to-Case** or **Enhanced Email**, which is automatically enabled for most customers.

If you want to be able to relate Email Message records to other objects (besides cases), then it is recommended that you enable Enhanced Email.

It means that EmailMessage can be used for other objects as well other then Case.

So **RelatedToId**- is the Id of that object record (nonhuman objects such as accounts, opportunities, campaigns, cases, or custom objects.) and

**ParentId** - is always the Id of case record to which email is associated.

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm)

Comment: What is the meaning of nonhuman objects?

Comment: @Sarang Non Human means objects which are related to things which are related to humans but they themselves are not human. For example Contact is a Human object because it directly represents a Human but Case represents the cases logged by Humans.

Comment: thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 8):

Originally, EmailMessage was only available for use with the Case object. The ParentId represents the Case the email is associated with. Now that email messages are available for use with other objects, the RelatedToId represents any object the EmailMessage is associated with (including Case). See the [Object Reference for Case](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

If we activate `Enhanced Email` then only `Related To` field is available, otherwise not.

`Parent Id` is always be available in `EmailMessage` object.

> Enhanced Email elevates email to a standard Salesforce object, with customization options and an API. Emails are no longer stored as tasks, but as full-featured records, complete with details, related lists, and collaboration tools. On email records, users can view their messages exactly as their customers do, complete with formatting.

Also, refer [Enhanced email and the Email Message object](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000239922&type=1)

- When Enhanced Email is activated, emails sent from Salesforce are logged as Email Messages and Tasks.
- The email messages are displayed in the Related List on the Object the email is sent from.
- The Tasks are not displayed on records in Salesforce with Enhanced Email activated.